# Pass a JSON object to an url with requests

Tags: python, urllib2, freebase

So, I want to use Kenneth' excellent [requests module](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/). Stumbled up this problem while trying to use the [Freebase API](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/API).

Basically, their API looks like that:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=...
```

as a query, they expect a JSON object, here's one that will [return a list of wines with their country and percentage of alcohol](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%5B%7B%22country%22%3Anull%2C%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22percentage_alcohol%22%3Anull%2C%22percentage_alcohol%3E%22%3A0%2C%22type%22%3A%22%2Ffood%2Fwine%22%7D%5D):

```
[{
  "country":       null,
  "name":          null,
  "percentage_alcohol": null,
  "percentage_alcohol>": 0,
  "type":          "/food/wine"
}]​
```

Of course, we'll have to escape the hell out of this before passing it to an URL, so the actual query will look like this:

```
 fullurl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%5B%7B%22percentage_alcohol%3E%22%3A+0%2C+%22country%22%3A+null%2C+%22type%22%3A+%22%2Ffood%2Fwine%22%2C+%22name%22%3A+null%2C+%22percentage_alcohol%22%3A+null%7D%5D'
```

Now,

```
r = requests.get(fullurl)
print r.status_code
>>> 400
```

because the site claims it couldn't parse the query.

```
r2 = urllib2.urlopen(fullurl)
print r2.getcode()
>>> 200
```

No problem here, I get a proper return. Interestingly,

```
# This is the url of our requests.get request
print urllib2.urlopen(r.url).getcode() 
>>> 200
```

Why? Am I using the module wrong? Or is it a bug in `requests`?

Comment: Use the `json` module, if you aren't already.

Answer (score 8):

It works for me. Here's what I did:

```
>>> params = [{"country": None,
...            "name": None,
...            "percentage_alcohol": None,
...            "percentage_alcohol>": 0,
...            "type": "/food/wine"
...          }]
>>> import json
>>> params_json = json.dumps(params)

>>> import requests
>>> url = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%s"
>>> r = requests.get(url % params_json)
>>> r.status_code
200

>>> content_json = json.loads(r.content)
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(content_json)
{u'result': [{u'country': u'New Zealand',
              u'name': u'2003 Cloudy Bay Sauvignon Blanc',
              u'percentage_alcohol': 13.5,
              u'type': u'/food/wine'},
             {u'country': u'France',
              u'name': u'G.H. Mumm Cordon Rouge Brut',
              u'percentage_alcohol': 12.0,
              u'type': u'/food/wine'},
....
```

I cut the rest off for brevity. There are 100 results. `requests.__version__ == '0.10.6'`

Comment: Gah I was just typing out this exact example. I doubt the OP was using the json module to serialize the python object. He was probably trying to manually escape a json string.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. It's probably why it wasn't parsing correctly