# Shutting off URL Encoding in Python Requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to pass JSON directly in a URL to [communicate with the Ecobe API](https://www.ecobee.com/home/developer/api/documentation/v1/operations/get-runtime-report.shtml). No matter how I try to format the data, it gets escaped in the URL. Requests used to allow you to pass a config parameter in the call and that had an option to shut off encoding, but it has been removed (so the [answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13653283/7376) no longer works). The only reference I can see in the docs is to something in [requests.defaults](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/api/#configurations) but I can't figure out how to set that. Because of this, my URL has all the JSON formatting URL-escaped instead of looking like what the API wants:

```
GET https://api.ecobee.com/1/runtimeReport?format=json&body={"startDate": "2010-01-01","endDate": "2010-01-02","columns": "zoneHVACmode,zoneCalendarEvent","selection":{"selectionType":"thermostats","selectionMatch": 123456789012"}}
```

Additionally, I've tried enough shotgun approaches (including the [one in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503383/pass-a-json-object-to-an-url-with-requests)) I'm not sure what's the best/ most efficient way to do this if it did work, so here's (an abbreviated version of) my current code in case there's a better option:

```
self.api_url = 'https://api.ecobee.com/%s?format=json&%s'
data = {
    'startDate': start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    'endDate': end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    'columns': 'auxHeat1,compCool1,outdoorHumidity,zoneAveTemp,zoneCoolTemp,zoneHeatTemp',
    'includeSensors': 'true',
    'selection': self.selection_info
}
endpoint = 'runtimeReport'
params_json = simplejson.dumps(params)
response = requests.get(self.api_url % (endpoint, params_json), headers=self._get_headers())
```

Comment: using requests.post will let you pass a data dictionary

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly how you're communicating with the API from your code, but why not use a `urllib2` request and pass it the JSON data, with the JSON encoding? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290522/urllib2-and-json. Edit: Oh, I see, you're using Python requests. A post should do it, as @JoranBeasley mentioned.

Comment: But the API wants it as a GET request. Will edit to clarify the problem @jsalonen.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it can be done any longer. Every URL gets passed through [requote_uri in utils.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L375). And unless I'm missing something, the fact this API wants JSON with spaces in a GET parameter is a bad idea.